# How to setup Airflow custom email template

Tags: airflow

In the `airflow.cfg`, I have set how I need my email to look like but when an email is sent, the settings/layout I have specified is not being applied.

```
subject_template = 'Airflow alert: {{ti}}'

# File that will be used as the template for Email content (which will be rendered using Jinja2).
# If not set, Airflow uses a base template.
# Example: html_content_template = /path/to/my_html_content_template_file
html_content_template = (
        'Try {{try_number}} out of {{max_tries + 1}}<br>'
        'Job Name: {{ti.dag_id}}<br>'
        'Task Id: {{ti.task_id}}<br>'
        'Exception: {{exception_html}}<br>'
        'Log: <a href={{ti.log_url}} target="_blank">Link</a><br>'
        'Host: {{ti.hostname}}<br>'
        'Log file: {{ti.log_filename}}<br>')
```

What I'm I missing?

Comment: I wonder if my answer below was helpful to you?

Comment: @NicoE , is ``once we get it, you immediately start receiving the alerts. Mohan, `` a standard html file? What will be the format?

Comment: The content of the file will be rendered [from a string](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#jinja2.Environment.from_string), so I guess you could safely use .html but is not really mandatory. [source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8fa976e514a411a1ecefa011f57416cf1fe09702/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L2171)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of [html_content_template](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#html-content-template):

> File that will be used as the template for Email content (which will be rendered using Jinja2). If not set, Airflow uses a base template.

I guess the expected value would be something like:

```
html_content_template = /path/to/my_html_content_template_file
```

Try creating a file with the template and providing the path to that file in the settings.